# SQL Query: How can I get data of row with number 1000 direclty?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, row-number

If I have a SQL Table called `Persons` that contain about 30000 rows and I want to make a SQL query that retrieve the data of row number 1000 ... I got it by non professional way by making the following query

```
Select Top 1 * from 
(
    Select top 1000 *
    From Persons
    Order By ID 
)A
Order By A.ID desc
```

But I feel that's a more optimized query that can do that ... can any lead me to perfect query ?
Note : table contain PK column called "ID" but it's not sequential

Answer (score 3):

`row_number` is the best approach but as you only want a single row be sure to look at the plan. It might turn out better to identify the desired row then join back onto the original table to retrieve additional columns.

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) AS RN
         FROM   master..spt_values)
SELECT name,
       number,
       type,
       low,
       high,
       status
FROM   T1
WHERE  RN = 1000;
```

Gives

> Table 'spt_values'. Scan count 1, logical reads **2005**
>
> CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 19 ms.

[image: plan 1]

```
WITH T2
     AS (SELECT number,
                type,
                name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) AS RN
         FROM   master..spt_values)
SELECT TOP 1 C.name,
             C.number,
             C.type,
             C.low,
             C.high,
             C.status
FROM   T2
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM   master..spt_values v
                    WHERE  v.number = T2.number
                           AND v.type = T2.type
                           AND ( v.name = T2.name
                                  OR ( v.name IS NULL
                                       AND T2.name IS NULL ) )) C
WHERE  RN = 1000;
```

Gives

> Table 'spt_values'. Scan count 1, logical reads **7**
>
> CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

[image: Plan 2]

Comment: Hey, how come? If I understand all this correctly, the effect is as if I knew the right row beforehand and simply needed to select it using the filter by (the already known) number, type and name. Is that it?

Comment: @Andriy M - The first (bad) plan does 1000 bookmark lookups (it retrieves the values for the additional columns even though these values will not be needed for 999 of those rows). The second plan uses the same index as the first plan but does not do these bookmark lookups it only retrieves the uncovered columns for the one row that will finally be returned.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2005+ you can use the following:

```
WITH MyCte AS 
(
    SELECT
        [CategoryId]
        ,[CategoryName]
        ,[CategoryDescription]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CategoryId ASC) AS RowNum
    FROM
        [Carmack].[dbo].[job_Categories]
)
SELECT *
FROM    MyCte
WHERE   RowNum = 3
```

Comment: Try to run this sql you will always have the below exception 
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'RowNumber'.

Comment: Yup...you're right. I realized that a couple of minutes ago. I've corrected it since. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select * from Person P
where 999 = ( select count(id) from Person P1 , Person P2 
              where P1.id = P.id and P2.id < P1.id)
```

Comment: @SpaceCracker -- Since you mention your "non-professional" approach. It is generally considered bad practice in relational databases to attach any meaning or significance to the physical order of rows in the table. No professional database programmer would do so. You should regard the table as a jumbled bag of objects (rows) having no order until your query's ORDER BY clause imposes order on them. And the ORDER BY clause should refer to column(s) you have defined. If you want a specific row, you retrieve it using the primary key or an alternate unique key, e,g.  ... WHERE ID = 1000.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.