# MSSQL 2008 R2 Selecting rows withing certain range - Paging - What is the best way

Tags: sql-server, select, paging, rows, between

Currently this sql query is able to select between the rows i have determined. But are there any better approach for this ?

```
  select * from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Id desc) as RowId 
                 from tblUsersMessages ) dt
  where RowId between 10 and 25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your indexes.

Sometimes this can be better

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblUsersMessages
WHERE  Id IN (SELECT Id
              FROM   (select Id,
                             ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Id desc) as RowId
                      from   tblUsersMessages) dt
              WHERE  RowId between 10 and 25)
```

If a narrower index exists that can be used to quickly find the `Id` values within the range. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441839/sql-query-how-can-i-get-data-of-row-with-number-1000-direclty/5442376#5442376) for an example that demonstrates the type of issue that can arise.

You need to check the execution plans and output of `SET STATISTICS IO ON` for your specific case.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer . I tried and both takes same time.  these are my indexes : http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/7168/indexes.png

Comment: i tried with IO and logical reads are a lot better at yours. at your style logical read is : Scan count 1, logical reads 493 and this is at my style : Scan count 1, logical reads 769  -  selecting rows between 100 and 250

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - That isn't what I would have expected. Is it doing a scan of the non clustered index and a sort to get the ids? I would have thought that as the clustered index is on `id` your original query would be the best one but if you were to start doing queries on much further ranges such as `WHERE  RowId between 10000 and 10025` you might consider adding an additional non clustered index on `id` and using the version in my answer. But maybe your table is quite wide? In which case it is using that other NCI in preference anyway.

Comment: yes you are right. i am also adding another where clause : http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/5114/resulti.png

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - Ah right yes. In that case the `NCI` covers the query so the second version will be more efficient as the ranges you are using get further from the start. Does the version in your question do a clustered index scan or does it use the NCI and do key lookups? If it does key lookups then it will be doing these completely unnecessarily for rows 1-100.

Comment: I am not expert with MSSQL :) So i did not understand your last question. But this table is for private messaging system. Here the create table query : http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/148/createtable.png

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - In SSMS on the "Query" menu turn on the "Include Actual Execution Plan" option and run them both.

Comment: Here the full view of execution plan : http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/9196/fullview.png

Comment: Yes the 2nd version cuts down on 100 unnecessary key lookups that don't contribute to the final result.

Comment: How do you read these values. Since relative the batch is low does it mean it is better. Are there any good tutorial which i also can learn :D thank you.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Just experience looking at plans. To get started on that you could look at this free ebook from Redgate [Dissecting SQL Server Execution Plans](http://www.red-gate.com/our-company/about/book-store/assets/sql-server-execution-plans.pdf) and yes generally the low batch cost is better but these are just estimated costs and can sometimes be wrong.